# python comples dictionary understanding

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Hi I am trying to resolve  dict and print the values based on success 
if the value in "success" is True than add 1  otherwise 0.
for ex: dictionary is

```
info = {'data': {'sample1': {'item': 'fruit1',
                             'id': 1,
                             'results': {'Apple': [{
                                 'start_ts': 1487579550,
                                 'success': True}],
                                 'Mango': [{
                                     'start_ts': 1487579550,
                                     'success': True}]
                             }
                             },
                 'sample2': {'item': 'fruit1',
                             'id': 2,
                             'results': {'Apple': [{
                                 'start_ts': 1487579550,
                                 'success': True}],
                                 'Mango': [{
                                     'start_ts': 1487579550,
                                     'success': False}]
                             }
                             },
                 'sample3': {'item': 'fruit2',
                             'id': 3,
                             'results': {'Apple': [{
                                 'start_ts': 1487579550,
                                 'success': True}],
                                 'Mango': [{
                                     'start_ts': 1487579550,
                                     'success': False}]
                             }
                             }
                 }}
```

output should be based on success for all items of "fruit1" and fruit2 and need to increment.

output:

```
        Apple    Mango    
fruit1  2         1
fruit2  1         0
```

what is best  way to iterate this complex dictionary.
I am trying some basic code:

```
for k, v in info.items():
    for i,sample in v.items():
      pprint.pprint(sample['results']) # Prints diction of Apples and Mango
```

Comment: have you tried to do anything yourself?

Comment: Using simple for loops and count vars must be enough. I hope that you want is to learn how to do this most efficient possible, so maybe you must show us that you are trying before to ask.

Comment: I think that you have an error in the code sample, because if you have a key called `data`  and is a list of samples, you need store the samples like a list using `[ ]` like the value of the key `data`.  And to make this easier you could delete the name of sample, like `sample1`,  if you are which generate the dict.

Answer (score 0):

Well, like very simple first approach you can do something like this:

```
fruit1 = {'Apple': 0, 'Mango': 0}
fruit2 = {'Apple': 0, 'Mango': 0}

for k, v in info['data'].items():
    if v['item'] == 'fruit1':
        if v['results']['Apple'][0]['success']:
            fruit1['Apple'] += 1
        if v['results']['Mango'][0]['success']:
            fruit1['Mango'] += 1

    if v['item'] == 'fruit2':
        if v['results']['Apple'][0]['success']:
            fruit2['Apple'] += 1
        if v['results']['Mango'][0]['success']:
            fruit2['Mango'] += 1


print 'fruit1: {}'.format(fruit1)
print 'fruit2: {}'.format(fruit2)
```

Output:

```
fruit1: {'Mango': 1, 'Apple': 2}
fruit2: {'Mango': 0, 'Apple': 1}
```

Only if always the name of the fruits are the same (fruit1 and 2) and these are always Apple and Mango. But the best will be that this not be important, you can work from here to achieve your goal in your domain. This is a bit dirty and of course not optimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways to get the info you want, like this for example

```
result={}
for sample in info["data"].values():
    name = sample["item"]
    inner = result.setdefault(name,{})
    for fruit, value in sample["results"].items():
        if value[0]["success"]:
            inner[fruit] = inner.get(fruit,0) + 1
print(result)
```

Explanation: First we decide how to get the result, in this case I chose a dictionary which key would be the "fruit1", "fruit2", etc and their values would be another dictionary with the number of "Apple", "Mango", etc found inside.
Then we start by iterating over the value of the key "data" as that is the one that have the information we want, then with [`setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) we first set the initial empty inner dictionary for the value of the corresponding name and get it in the `inner` variable, then we follow by iterating over the items of the corresponding result (aka the fruits) and count the number of success, using [`get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) so the first time we get 0 for its count

output

```
{'fruit1': {'Apple': 2, 'Mango': 1}, 'fruit2': {'Apple': 1}}
```

once you get to that, you get here, you can print it in any way you want

---

this a variation of the same using generator expressions and the [collections](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html) module

```
from pprint import pprint
from collections import Counter, defaultdict

compact = ( (s["item"],( k for k,v in s["results"].items() if v[0]["success"] ) ) for s in info["data"].values())
result = defaultdict(Counter)
for k,v in compact:
    result[k].update(v)
pprint(result)
```

output

```
defaultdict(<class 'collections.Counter'>,
            {'fruit1': Counter({'Apple': 2, 'Mango': 1}),
             'fruit2': Counter({'Apple': 1})})
```

Answer (score 0):

A short solution using pandas, since nested dictionaries is a good entry for tables :

```
pan=pd.Panel.from_dict(info['data'])
def repl(s): return s['item'] if  ~isnan(s.id) and s.results[0]['success'] else None
df=pan.apply(repl,'minor')
sta=df.stack().reset_index()
cnt=sta.groupby(['level_0',0]).count().unstack().fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Final result (`cnt`) :

```
         fruit1 fruit2               
Apple         2      1
Mango         1      0
```

In the detail :

```
pan=pd.Panel.from_dict(info['data'])
```

All is then automatically 3D organized :

```
<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 3 (items) x 2 (major_axis) x 3 (minor_axis)
Items axis: sample1 to sample3
Major_axis axis: Apple to Mango
Minor_axis axis: id to results
```

Define now a function to select the good fruits and reduce to 2D:

```
def repl(s): return s['item'] if  ~isnan(s.id) and s.results[0]['success'] else None
df=pan.apply(repl,'minor')
```

for :

```
      sample1 sample2 sample3
Apple  fruit1  fruit1  fruit2
Mango  fruit1    None    None
```

Finally reorganize in 1D:

```
sta=df.stack().reset_index()
```

`None` values are dropped:

```
  level_0  level_1       0
0   Apple  sample1  fruit1
1   Apple  sample2  fruit1
2   Apple  sample3  fruit2
3   Mango  sample1  fruit1
```

And count :

```
cnt=sta.groupby(['level_0',0]).count().unstack().fillna(0).astype(int)
```